# How to add other elements to an array[size] (index 0 is already set)

Tags: arrays, c

im really new to programming, c is my first language

i want to create an array with a size set by scanf
it should start with startValue (second scanf) and then printf the rest of the array but with startvalue+1

so for example if i type in:
3 // --> size of the array 
4 // --> my starting point/startValue

the programm should give me:
4
5
6

after several hours of watching videos/reading online and trial and error i just dont know how to solve this problem :( i really appreciate your help thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size;
    int startValue;
    scanf("%d\n %d", &size, &startValue);

    int array[size];
    array[0] = startValue;

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C you can't do that

Comment: Your array is not initialized -- it has random values in it. The syntax you used will not initialize the array elements, except for the assignment statement you have.

Comment: Not your problem, but since you're just starting out, here's a tip about `scanf`.  It's just about the most apparently useful, but actually perfectly awful, function in all of C.  I suggest always printing a prompt beforehand, and only reading one number at a time, with dirt-simple formats.  Like this: `printf("Enter size:\n"); scanf("%d", &size); printf("Enter start value:\n"); scanf("%d", &startValue);`.  It's also a good idea to check `scanf`'s return value, to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: Please make sure your `printf` calls always have that `\n` at the end of the strings they print, and please use *only* these four `scanf` formats: `"%d"`, `"%f"`, `"%lf"`, `"%s"`.  If you're feeling bold you can try a fifth: `" %c"`. But note that it's got a curious extra space in it, and that's no accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want desired output: 4 5 6
for this you need to assign value to the rest of elements also as did with

```
array[0] = startValue;
```

I've tried to assign it the way you wanted, may be this would help you to understand

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size;
    int startValue;
    scanf("%d\n %d", &size, &startValue);

    int array[size];

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        array[i]= startValue;
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
        startValue=startValue+1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm assigning values to
array[0] & array[1] through this

```
array[i]= startValue;
```

and incrementing the value of startValue by +1 through this

```
startValue=startValue+1;
```

line

Comment: thank you very much !! :( now i understand